# Issues with new installation of joomla 2.5 that connects to old database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

I want to connect our new installation of Joomla 2.5 to our old database in order to salvage content.  I'm cleaning up someone else's errors without having full nothing of what that person actually did to cause the problems.

Bottom line, our site went down because of an error in judgement by that new webmaster and instead of him restoring the site he built a new site in Wix and forgot about the old content. That was in July.

The database is still there.  So, after the new installation of Joomla 2.5,  I edited the configuration.php to point to the old database and now I can see lots more content on the admin backend but the frontend is all messed up...and the backend is not fully in tact either, despite the fact that I can see more stuff.

I'm not a trained coder.  I can make changes to coding with good instructions.  I'd like to know if anyone can help me.

On the back end, I'm getting this error when I click on an article to edit it...

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in /home/content/08/9859108/html/libraries/joomla/application/component/controllerform.php on line 341

On the front end at  [new.district79.org](http://new.district79.org) It shows these error messages.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/08/9859108/html/components/com_content/models/articles.php on line 497
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/08/9859108/html/libraries/joomla/database/database/mysql.php on line 293

Thanks so much. Apologies if this is not appropriate for this forum/community.

Comment: add your code as well.

Comment: what was the previous version of Joomla, before installing 2.5? Are you migrating from old version to 2.5 version of Joomla?

Comment: It was definitely 2.5.XX.   I'm just not sure what the last digits were.  I haven't touched it since July and am now taking it back over. But, both are 2.5—the old version and the new install.

Comment: Which code should I add?  From the config file?

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju what code do you want to me provide? Thanks

Comment: `controllerform.php`, `articles.php`